# AudioQueueBufferRef in SimplePCMRecorder showing error in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to connect Alexa from iPhone, for that I am using a sample which is written in swift 2.2 on [Github](https://github.com/kevinguebert/iOS-Alexa)

So I need to convert that into Swift 3.0

Migrated from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0 from xcode is done which resolved almost all the errors, now the only error which is left is related to AudioQueueBufferRef

Swift 2.2:

```
self.recorderState = RecorderState(
            setupComplete: false,
            dataFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription(),
            queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef>.alloc(1),
            buffers: Array<AudioQueueBufferRef>(count: numberBuffers, repeatedValue: nil),
            recordFile: AudioFileID(),
            bufferByteSize: 0,
            currentPacket: 0,
            isRunning: false,
            recordPacket: 0,
            errorHandler: nil)
```

Swift 3.0: (just for param `buffers`)

```
let audioBufferQueue = Array<AudioQueueBufferRef>(repeating: nil, count: numberBuffers)
```

and in swift 2.2 it is working fine but in swift 3.0 it is showing an error

> /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/iOS-Alexa-master copy/iOS
>   Alexa/AVS/SimplePCMRecorder.swift:28:32: Expression type
>   'Array' (aka
>   'Array>') is ambiguous without
>   more context

[SimplePCMRecorder of Swift 2.2 on Github](https://github.com/kevinguebert/iOS-Alexa/blob/master/iOS%20Alexa/AVS/SimplePCMRecorder.swift)

I have searched on google and stackoverflow but didn't find the solution. I tried rewriting and google things but no resolved.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found the solution? any luck?

Comment: No yet, didn't found any solution :(

Comment: Oh man, I'm stuck here. But will let you know if I found any solution.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Please let me know if you get working code in swift 3.0 :(

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Any update ?

Comment: No I didn't found any solution

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, use `AudioQueueBufferRef?` instead of `AudioQueueBufferRef`:

```js
let buffers = Array<AudioQueueBufferRef?>(repeating: nil, count: numberBuffers)

// and allocate each buffer
for i in 0 ..< buffers.count {
  AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(inQueue!, bufferSize, &buffers[i])
}
```